# Insert chart into Excel content pane app by using Javascript API?

Tags: office-2013, office-app

In App for `Office`, it support to create task pane app by using `javascript/html`, now i want to know how to insert chart into `Excel` content app by using `JavaScript API`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow. A content app is by its nature insertable. If what you want to do is to create a chart that can bind to data (like this app: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/store/people-graph-WA104104476.aspx?queryid=ff2c275c%2Dad40%2D4fee%2Da071%2Dd94e18b134ec&css=people%20chart&CTT=1  ) then you need to look at the binding APIs; this is a good article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166930.aspx